# Why doesn't Sender = Recipient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, discord.js, bots

I've been converting Discord bot code that was written for discord.js v11 over to v12.  The only part of the code I still can't get to work is a loop that utilizes enmap data:
My current code:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  let serverlist = client.guilds.cache.array(); // Grabs the Guilds.
  const server = message.guild.id; // Key for client.Networks
  let Sender = client.Networks.get(server); // Key is already defined with 'server' there is no point typing it out again unless it is different.
  const input = args.join(" "); // Joins the arguments together.
  for (let i = 0; i < serverlist.length; i++) {
    let Recipient = client.Networks.get(serverlist[i].id);
    Recipient = parseInt(Recipient);
    //if (Sender == Recipient) {
    if (server === serverlist[i].id) {
      try {
        if (
          !serverlist[i].channels.cache.find(
            (channel) => channel.name === "broadcast"
          )
        )
          continue; // If the channel it just skips it, and starts from the top again.
```

Here's the original code:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  var serverlist = client.guilds.array();
  console.log(client.Networks);

  var server = message.guild.channels;
  var Sender = client.Networks.get(message.guild.name);
  const input = args.join(" "); //rejoins arg array into string
  for (var i = 0; i < serverlist.length; i++) {
    //get network id of message sender
    var Recipient = client.Networks.get(serverlist[i].name);
    Recipient = parseInt(Recipient);

    if (Sender == Recipient) {
      try {
        var serv = serverlist[i].channels.find(
          (serv) => serv.name === "broadcast"
        );
```

Enmap data seems to be stored fine.  keys are server IDs, and the value with each key is the name of the network the servers are part of. This loop is supposed to transmit a message to the #broadcast channel on each server in the network.  The code fails at the Sender === Recipient check.  the try just ends with a catch for if the #broadcast channel is not found on one of the servers the bot is checking.
Why are Sender and Recipient not matching, and is this loop structured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you use `parseInt(Recipient)` but not `parseInt(Sender)`. So your `Sender` might be a string and your `Recipient` an integer. In your old code, you compared using loose equality `==`, which performs [type coercion](https://www.google.com/search?q=js%20type%20coercion&cad=h). But in your current code you are using strict equality `===` which cannot ever be true if the two values being checked are different type (string and int).

If you don't have a particular need for the sender or recipient to actually be a number, I'd recommend just removing the `Recipient = parseInt(Recipient)` line. If you do, I'd recommend using the [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus):

```
var Sender = +client.Networks.get(message.guild.name);
var Recipient = +client.Networks.get(serverlist[i].name);
```

Comment: Yes, I have in fact changed it to user server IDs rather than names in the v12 code.
I'm also considering wiping all the sender/recipient code and just use something like Enmap.ForEach or Enmap.Filter since the loop is checking an enmap to send to every server with the same value (network name)  That would probably be a lot simpler.

Comment: @Startropic1 So you did! Forgive me, I didn't notice that change. I'll strike out that part of the answer since it's irrelevant.